# How do I unpack a numpy array of tuples into an ndarray?

Tags: python, numpy

I have a 2D numpy array with elements of the type `np.void` that are essentially tuples.  Is there an efficient way to unpack the values in these tuples to a 3rd dimension without looping through each element of the array?

For example, the 2D array looks something like:

```
a = np.array([[(1, 2,  3), (1, 2,  3), (1, 2, 3)],
       [(1, 2,  3), (1, 2, 3), (1, 2, 3)],
       [(1, 2, 3), (1, 2, 3), (1, 2, 3)]],
      dtype=[('B4', '<u2'), ('B3', '<u2'), ('B2', '<u2')])
```

Where,

```
a.shape = (3,3)
a[0,0] = (1,2,3)
```

I'd like to unpack each element so the resulting array would be 3D
and look something like this:

```
b.shape = (3,3,3)
b[0,0,0] = 1
b[0,0,1] = 2
b[0,0,2] = 3
```

in other words,

```
b[:,:,0] == 
array([[1, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 1]])
b[:,:,1] == 
array([[2, 2, 2],
       [2, 2, 2],
       [2, 2, 2]])
b[:,:,2] == 
array([[3, 3, 3],
       [3, 3, 3],
       [3, 3, 3]])
```

I know there's gotta be a more efficient way to do this other than looping through each element, but I'm not really familiar with dealing with np.void elements.

Thanks

To clarify, `a more efficient solution` meaning compared to something like

```
new_array = np.zeros((a.shape + (3,)))
for i in range(a.shape[0]):
    for j in range(a.shape[-1]):
        new_array[i, j, 0] = a[i, j][0]
        new_array[i, j, 1] = a[i, j][1]
        new_array[i, j, 2] = a[i, j][2]
```

Comment: what do you mean by _more efficient way_? What is your baseline?

Comment: _more efficient_ meaning writing fewer lines of code than a nested for loop to go through each element, extract and assign each value to the new array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
In [601]: a = np.array([[(1, 2,  3), (1, 2,  3), (1, 2, 3)], 
     ...:        [(1, 2,  3), (1, 2, 3), (1, 2, 3)], 
     ...:        [(1, 2, 3), (1, 2, 3), (1, 2, 3)]], 
     ...:       dtype=[('B4', '<u2'), ('B3', '<u2'), ('B2', '<u2')])                 
In [602]: a.dtype                                                                    
Out[602]: dtype([('B4', '<u2'), ('B3', '<u2'), ('B2', '<u2')])
In [603]: a.shape                                                                    
Out[603]: (3, 3)
```

This is a structured array, with a compound dtype.  The tuples display individual elements of the 2d array.

Recent numpy versions have added a function to conveniently convert structured arrays to unstructured:

```
In [606]: b=rf.structured_to_unstructured(a)                                         
In [607]: b                                                                          
Out[607]: 
array([[[1, 2, 3],
        [1, 2, 3],
        [1, 2, 3]],

       [[1, 2, 3],
        [1, 2, 3],
        [1, 2, 3]],

       [[1, 2, 3],
        [1, 2, 3],
        [1, 2, 3]]], dtype=uint16)
In [608]: b[:,:,1]                                                                   
Out[608]: 
array([[2, 2, 2],
       [2, 2, 2],
       [2, 2, 2]], dtype=uint16)
```

---

`a` has 3 fields.  Individual fields can be accessed by name:

```
In [610]: a['B4']                                                                    
Out[610]: 
array([[1, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 1]], dtype=uint16)
```

That means you could construct the 3d array by concatenating the 3 individual fields:

```
np.stack([a['B4'],a['B3'],a['B2']])
```

This is like your last solution, but without the `i,j` iteration.

---

The `view` approach in the other answer works in this case because all fields have the same `dtype`, `<u2`.  That means the same underlying data can be viewed as individual `<u2` elements, or a groups of 3 of these.

```
import numpy.lib.recfunctions as rf
```

The `rf.structured_to_unstructured` works in more general cases where `view` does not, such as a mix of dtypes, (e.g. floats and integers).

Answer (score 0):

You can view as a standard `numpy` array to allow for the indexing you're after.

```
b = a.view('(3,)<u2')
```

```
array([[[1, 2, 3],
        [1, 2, 3],
        [1, 2, 3]],

       [[1, 2, 3],
        [1, 2, 3],
        [1, 2, 3]],

       [[1, 2, 3],
        [1, 2, 3],
        [1, 2, 3]]], dtype=uint16)
```

---

```
>>> b.shape
(3, 3, 3)
>>> b[:, :, 0]
array([[1, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 1]], dtype=uint16)
```

Comment: That worked great! Thanks.  Do you have a reference for the `'(3,)<u2'` syntax?